# How many LMD's are currently operating in the Marvel universe?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

As of the end of *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* season 7, we see that

> Agent Coulson and Agent Davis are LMD's (Life-Model Decoys) and actively in operation for S.H.I.E.L.D..

However, in earlier seasons, we've seen LMDs (like a couple dozen Daisy Johnson LMDs) created by AIDA, and there were also LMDs of most of the original S.H.I.E.L.D. team. How many and which LMDs are in operation as of the end of Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.? A number of how many plus the names of each one would be useful.

Comment: Chances are nobody knows. Aside from Coulson and Davis, all the other LMDs were in the SHIELD base at the end of season 4, which we've not gone back to since.

Comment: As many as the plots demand, both current and future 